# Flutter Provider: notifyListeners does not update AlertDialog widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm using `Provider` to provide some data to my screen and an alert dialog. Knowing that `AlertDialog` is scooped outside the widget tree, I added a `ChangeNotifierProvider` as a wrapper widget of that dialog. But still, the UI is not changing even though I made sure the values are updated in the provider state.

Code Snippet:

```
showTextDialog(BuildContext context) {
  final myModel = Provider.of<ServicesProvider>(context, listen: false);
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: myModel,
      child: AlertDialog(
        content: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Radio(
                    value: '0',
                    groupValue: myModel.paymentMethod,
                    onChanged: (value) => myModel.setPaymentMethod('0'),
                    activeColor: ColorResources.PRIMARY_COLOR,
                    toggleable: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: responsiveWidth(5)),
                  Text("Radio Button 1"),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: responsiveHeight(10)),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Radio(
                    value: '1',
                    groupValue: myModel.paymentMethod,
                    onChanged: (value) => myModel.setPaymentMethod('1'),
                    activeColor: ColorResources.PRIMARY_COLOR,
                    toggleable: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: responsiveWidth(5)),
                  Flexible(child: Text("Radio Button 2")),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried changing `listen: false` to `listen: true`?

Comment: Yes, it's not allowed to set the listen to true outside the build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main idea behind your problem is that you do not subscribe to the changes of your `ServicesProvider`. You can replace `Provider.of<ServicesProvider>(context, listen: false);` with `context.read<ServicesProvider>();` that is a more concise syntax using extension methods.

Based on the Provider [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider):

> context.read<T>(), which returns T without listening to it. <...> It's worth noting that context.read<T>() won't make a widget rebuild when the value changes and it cannot be called inside StatelessWidget.build/State.build. On the other hand, it can be freely called outside of these methods.

What you have done already with `final myModel = Provider.of<ServicesProvider>(context, listen: false);` is that you only retrieved the reference to `ServicesProvider`. However, this way you do not subscribe to the changes inside the model - this is exactly what the documentation explains.

To resolve this, you can move the `AlertDialog` into a separate widget, e.g. `MyDialog`. There is a practical reason - it's just easier to understand that now you are not using the same context and you should access the re-provided `ServicesProvider` model. Now, by using `context.watch<ServicesProvider>()` (you could use the `Consumer` widget as well if you would like to), you can subscribe to the changes of your model. Thus, when there is a change for the `paymentMethod` value inside the model (you can do it by calling the `setPaymentMethod()` method on model), it triggers UI rebuild (`notifyListeners()` does its work) and you get the expected output.

You could find the recreated and resolved issue [here](https://dartpad.dev/f542682880bf16d81d6f6518fa15b11f).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. I think I have to read about Provider again.